# Cleaner method for list comprehension clean-up

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

This relates to my previous question: [Converting from nested lists to a delimited string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19612763/converting-from-nested-lists-to-a-delimited-string)

I have an external service that sends data to us in a delimited string format. It is lists of items, up to 3 levels deep. Level 1 is delimited by '|'. Level 2 is delimited by ';' and level 3 is delimited by ','. Each level or element can have 0 or more items. An simplified example is:
`a,b;c,d|e||f,g|h;;`

We have a function that converts this to nested lists which is how it is manipulated in Python.

```
def dyn_to_lists(dyn):  
    return [[[c for c in b.split(',')] for b in a.split(';')] for a in dyn.split('|')]
```

For the example above, this function results in the following:

```
>>> dyn = "a,b;c,d|e||f,g|h;;"
>>> print (dyn_to_lists(dyn))
[[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']], [['e']], [['']], [['f', 'g']], [['h'], [''], ['']]]
```

For lists, at any level, with only one item, we want it as a scalar rather than a 1 item list. For lists that are empty, we want them as just an empty string. I've came up with this function, which does work:

```
def dyn_to_min_lists(dyn):
    def compress(x): 
        return "" if len(x) == 0 else x if len(x) != 1 else x[0]

    return compress([compress([compress([item for item in mv.split(',')]) for mv in attr.split(';')]) for attr in dyn.split('|')])
```

Using this function and using the example above, it returns (***see update below**):

```
[[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']], 'e', '', ['f', 'g'], ['h', '', '']]
```

Being new to Python, I'm not confident this is the best way to do it. Are there any cleaner ways to handle this?

This will potentially have large amounts of data passing through it, are there any more efficient/scalable ways to achieve this?

**Update**

I found a bug in my original compress function. When an inner list has more than 1 item, the outer list cannot be removed - this would result in the conversion being non-reversible. For this, I've updated @Blender's compress function to be:

```
def __compress(x): 
    if len(x) > 1:
        return x
    elif not x:
        return ''
    else:
        if type(x[0]) != list:
            return x[0]
        else:
            return x
```

Now it returns the correct output of:

```
[[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']], 'e', '', [['f', 'g']], ['h', '', '']]
```

Comment: your list comprehensions iterate over the string several times. would it be faster to implement a grammar parser? if you really need to handle a lot of data like this.

Comment: Thanks @akonsu, wanted to start off with something that works then work on improving it from there. I'm looking into others ways in Python to achieve this. I'll update the Q if I get anything better working.

Comment: @akonsu - any links that might help?

Comment: well, first, I would write a grammar for this. then I am sure there are libraries for Python similar to yacc/bison. EDIT: here is a link: https://wiki.python.org/moin/LanguageParsing

Comment: @DanMcGrath would it be ok if the output was `[[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['f', 'g']], 'e', '', 'h', '', '']`?

Comment: @KDawG, unfortunately no. The positioning has very explicit meanings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a few things to speed it up:

- Get rid of the inner-most list comprehension: `[item for item in mv.split(',')]` becomes `mv.split(',')`. It's useless.
- Move the `compress` function outside of the `dyn_to_min_lists` function. You don't want it to be created each time you run `dyn_to_min_lists`.
- Using truthiness is faster than calling `len`, so replace `len(x) == 0` with `not x`.
- Reordering the conditions of your `compress` function so that the more common cases come up first will speed things up as well.

So the resulting code is:

```
def compress(x): 
    if len(x) > 1:
        return x
    elif not x:
        return ''
    else:
        return x[0]

def parse(s):
    return compress([
        compress([
            compress(b.split(',')) for b in a.split(';')
        ]) for a in s.split('|')
    ])
```

Here's a speed comparison:

```
>>> %timeit parse('a,b;c,d|e||f,g|h;;')
100000 loops, best of 3: 10 µs per loop
>>> %timeit dyn_to_min_lists('a,b;c,d|e||f,g|h;;')
10000 loops, best of 3: 15.6 µs per loop
```

It's about 36% faster on my computer. If this is a really critical part of your script, implement it in C and compile it into a C extension.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks Blender. It still essentially processes the string 3 times, so while your version is much better, my general algo for this is pretty horrid. I haven't written any C extensions for Python before, although I've done enough C programming that I should probably look into it. Thanks for the direction.